# SessionNotCreatedException when launching chromedriver and electron

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, electron

I'm am testing an electron app using selenium and suddenly getting this error after my electron app version changed when I try to launch my tests

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new >session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or >browser start-up failure.

I'm using:

- electron version 4.2.12
- chromedriver 2.42 (Ive tried 2.40 - 2.43)
- Selenium 4.0

And my setup is as follows:

```
String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")                 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectLocation + "/chromedriver.exe");
        
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource 
problems
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.setBinary("C:/Users/Public/ElectronApp.exe");
browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
pageConfig = new PageConfig(browser);
```